# Is there a frosting that's sweet like American Buttercream but textured like Italian Meringue Buttercream?

Tags: flavor, sugar, frosting

I know a lot of people find storebought frosting like Betty Crocker's to be vile anathema... but I love its taste.  For me, the sweeter the better! Which is why I was disappointed when I made a batch of Italian meringue buttercream and it was anything but sweet. However, I loooved its rich smoothness. (Conversely, I like the taste of American buttercream but not its texture.) My first instinct would simply be to add more sugar, but I'm worried that would ruin its creaminess.

Is there a way to sweeten an IMBC without impairing its texture, or a different type of frosting that's similarly textured but super sweet?  Or will I be forever condemned to choosing between taste and form?

Comment: You could find a sweetener alternative, like Tagatose, which is about twice as sweet as sugar. You then use some of that as a replacement for the sugar in the recipe until you find the sweetness you are looking for. I don't think I'd use Stevia for this as it has a bitter aftertaste.

Comment: @RonBeyer Smart! I never would have thought of getting a sweeter sugar. I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My wife uses [whipped cream frosting](https://bakingamoment.com/whipped-cream-frosting/), which is quite smooth and soft.

Basically it is cream-cheese frosting with whipped cream added in, and then beaten with a wire whisk beater (easiest to do in a cake-mixer).

A basic recipe is:

- 8 ounces cream cheese
- 1 cup powdered sugar
- 2 3/4 cups heavy cream, cold

Instructions:

1. Place the cream cheese and powdered sugar in a large bowl and beat
   on medium-low speed until smooth.
2. Turn the mixer down to medium-low speed and pour the heavy cream
   down the side of the bowl in a very slow and steady stream, stopping
   every now and then to scrape the bottom and sides of the bowl with a
   silicone spatula.
3. When all the cream has been added, turn the mixer up to medium-high
   and whip until the frosting holds stiff peaks.
4. Flavor it as you need, folding in the flavoring

You can sweeten any frosting fairly effectively with extra sugar or sweetener, however too much sugar will cause any frosting to collapse as it absorbs water from the air and other ingredients. If you want to make it extra sweet, use an artificial sweetener